# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2n)!}{{k!^2(n-k)!}^2}= \binom{2n}{n}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Show that
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2n)!}{k!^2(n-k)!^2}  = \binom{2n}{n}^2.$$

I tried canceling $2n!$ from both sides then moving $k!$ to right but still not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(2n)! \over k!^{2}\pars{n - k}!^{2}}}  = 
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n! \over k!\pars{n - k}!}\,{n! \over k!\pars{n - k}!}\,{\pars{2n}! \over n!\,n!} =
{2n \choose n}\
\underbrace{\ \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}^{2}}_{\ds{2n \choose n}\ }\ =\
\color{#f00}{{2n \choose n}^{2}}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   \begin{align}
> {2n \choose n} &= \bracks{x^{n}}\pars{1 + x}^{2n} =
> \bracks{x^{n}}\braces{\pars{1 + x}^{n}\pars{1 + x}^{n}}
> \\[3mm] & =
> \bracks{x^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\,\sum_{k' = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
> {n \choose n - k'}x^{k + k'} =
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{n \choose n - k}
> \end{align}

Comment: +1. I think it would be better as an underbrace, not an overbrace :)

Comment: @6005 Done. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've been trying the wrong steps.  Great Job!

Comment: @jim Glad to be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Also, to show that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 =\binom{2n}{n}$, we can look at $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n = (1+x)^{2n}$. The coefficient of $x^n$ in the left-hand side is $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2$ and the coefficient of $x^n$ in the right-hand side is $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: @user19405892 That is in the $\color{orange}{yellow\ note}$.

Answer (score 3):

For a combinatorial approach, the right-hand side counts ways of splitting $2n$ people into two groups of size $n$, twice; i.e., we assign half of the group $0$ and half of them $1$, and we assign half of them $a$ and half of them $b$.
All together, each person now is labeled either '$0a$', '$0b$', '$1a$', or '$1b$'.

On the left-hand side, the $k$th term is $\binom{2n}{k,k,n-k,n-k}$: it counts the number of ways to split $2n$ people into $k$ people with '$0a$', $k$ people with '$1b$', $n-k$ people with '$0b$', and $n-k$ people with '$1a$'.
This is summed up over all possible $k$.

Note that no matter how the $2n$ people are assigned into halves of $0/1$ and $a/b$ on the right-hand side, there will be the same number of '$0a$'s as '$1b$'s.
Thus this will correspond to some $k$ term on the left-hand side, so the two counts are the same, and so the equality is proved.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer was downvoted: it’s an excellent answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. Probably someone who either has not heard of combinatorial proofs or does not understand how it constitutes a proof.

Comment: Hi. 1. Can you please elaborate why the kth term is $\binom{2n}{k,k,n-k,n-k}$? Why aren't the $k$ and $n - k$ in another order? E.g. why not split 2n people into $N - K$ people with '0a', $N - K$ people with '1b', $K$ people with '0b', and $K$ people with '1a'? Or some other permutation of $k, k, n-k, n-k$?

Comment: 2. Why "there will be the same number of '0a's as '1b's."? The half assigned 0 MAY differ from the half assigned a. The half assigned 1 MAY differ from the half assigned b. Thus those people assigned 0a MAY differ from the half assigned 1b.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to edit your answer to respond to my comment, rather than starting a separate comment.

Comment: @ugro Thank you for your comments, I don't think this will require an answer update so I will respond in the comments. (1) Combinations are independent of the order of which is chosen; this can be shown algebraically or combinatorially. That is, $\binom{2n}{a, b, c, d} = \binom{2n}{b, c, a, d} = \binom{2n}{b, a, d, c}$ and so on.

Comment: (2) Your reasoning is not quite right here. Given that there are $k$ people assigned 0a, there are $n - k$ assigned 1a. Given that there are $n - k$ assigned 1a, there are $n - (n - k) = k$ assigned 1b. Hence the number of people assigned 0a and the number of people assigned 1b.

Comment: @6005 Thanks. I don't think you wrote this explicitly in your answer, but isn't there be the same number of $0b$'s as $1a$'s too?

Comment: @ugro yes that is correct